# How to protect websocket connection ip from being modified

Tags: websocket, ip, server

I am working on a small project to help me understand websockets better. I am making a simple browser game that connects to an ip via a websocket. There will be 3 ip addresses however I want to assign the user an ip and not have them able to modify it so they are unable to get on the same server as friends.

I will assign the ip based on how full the games are etc and this will be down via php. Currently although it connects to this ip, the user is able to use the console in a browser to modify the ip to one of the other ones.

I was thinking of sending a check number, so the web server sends this to the user along with the ip. It also sends it to the websocket server. Then when a user connects if the check number doesn't match it rejects the connection.

I'm new to websockets so I'm not sure if this would be easy to implement, so are there any easy solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the duty of other element, in particular the load balancer. How are you balancing the requests across those 3 servers? Does your load balancer support sticky sessions?

If not, probably you can record to which IP address the user connected first, and they if it connects to one of the other two later, you can return a HTTP 302 (Redirect) pointing to the server you want.

Cheers.